# Constructing a generalized linear model when the dependent variable has a Exponentially modified Gaussian distribution

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, statsmodels

I have some data where I have reason to believe the dependent variable $Y$ follows an Exponentially modified Gaussian distribution, i.e. $Y$ is the sum of one gaussian distributed stochastic variable $A$ and one exponentially distributed stochastic variable $B$,
$$ Y = A+B $$
I would like to construct a generalized linear model with this assumption. How can I do this? For example, in the python statsmodels package, I can do

```
model = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
```

But the family argument only accepts Binomial, Poisson, Neg. Binom., Gaussian, Gamma, Inv. Gauss, Tweedie. Is there any trick I can do or how would I go about this? What link function would I use?

Comment: This is not a standard model, so you would need to write your own likelihood function. You say that this is a GLM, so I presume there are some explanatory variables. Are both $A$ and $B$ functions of these variables?

Comment: @DoctorMilt I would assume both of them are. Initially I had a linear regression model $$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ... + \beta_i x_i + ... + \beta_p x_p.$$ 
I have read both that linear regression does and does not need $Y$ to be distributed gaussian. Atleast my residuals are. Since $Y$ is reaction times, usually distributed according to Exponentially modified Gaussian distribution, I thought I could do better by using GLM and assuming exgauss distribution. This is where I am at. I don't know if this is sound at all and would appreciate any help.

Comment: This distribution has three parameters: the mean ($\mu$) and variance ($\sigma^2$) of the Gaussian part, and the scale ($\theta$) of the Exponential part. Assuming that $\sigma^2$ is the same for every observation, you could write down a model where $\mu$ and $\log\theta$ are linear combinations of the explanatory variables.

Comment: The PDF of the exponentially modified Gaussian involves evaluating a convolution integral, so it includes the error function (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution). I am not very familiar with Python, but it is implemented efficiently in R.

Comment: @DoctorMilt I'm afraid I don't fully understand how to construct it yet, but I will take a look at generalized linear models in R, thanks. But just for a sanity check: I have confirmed that $Y$ as well as the residuals in a linear regression model better fits exgaussian rather than gaussian. Would it from this point make sense to construct a glm (in whatever way) where I try to set the "family" to exgaussian? What would I set the link function to?

Comment: GLM in statsmodels is only for families that are one-parameter linear exponential families (LEF), with fixed extra parameters and auxiliary scale if it is not fixed. Regression for distributions not in this family are implemented as generic maximum likelihood models. The `GenericLikelihoodModel` can be used for user provided likelihood functions. Note, AFAICS from the wikipedia page, the mean of the exponentially modified Gaussian is not of the form `link_inverse(linear_predictor)` as in GLM, so it will not fit into the GLM/LEF framework.

Comment: The big advantage of GLM/LEF is that the mean parameters are consistently estimated if the mean function (link) is correctly specified, but it does not require that variance function and distribution are correctly specified. That means we can treat all GLM/LEF families as quasi-maximum likelihood models. This is not the case for other distributions.

Comment: @Josef So I take it I can't use glm. So I can use scipy.stats.exponnorm.fit()(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponnorm.html ) to use maximum likelihood estimation to fit an exgauss distribution to my data and it fits the collected data of the dependent variable almost perfectly. But how can I use this to construct a model based on my data of independent variables? My end goal is to interpret and create confidence intervals for the coefficients of my model, think $\beta$ in $Y=A\beta$

Comment: Have you tried fitting a linear model and looking at the distribution of the residuals? Fitting a distribution to $\mathbf{Y}$ (the dependent variable) is not particularly useful in the presence of explanatory variables. Even if the errors are Gaussian, remember that each $Y_i$ has its own mean ($\mathbf{x}_i' \beta$), so the distribution will be a mixture of Gaussians.

Comment: Should you be open to Bayesian modeling, the brms package has the ex-Gaussian family. See here: [http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/ExGaussian.html](http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/ExGaussian.html).

Answer (score 2):

Generalized linear models assume that the response variable follows an exponential dispersion model (EDM) distribution. For fixed dispersion value, an EDM is a linear exponential family (LEF). As already pointed out by @Josef in a comment, the normal+exponential convolution distribution is not a LEF and hence there is no generalized linear model.

The whole point of generalized linear models is that the response distribution is determined by the mean-variance relationship.
The normal+exponential convolution does not have a characteristic mean-variance relationship, so it never could be a candidate for the generalized linear model framework.

The normal+exponential convolution distribution has however been used extensively in the bioinformatics literature for background correction of microarray intensities. I've listed a few references below. So there is existing software for estimating the parameters of the normal+exponential convolution.

If your intention is simply to model your response variable using covariates then the normal+exponential convolution might not be the best way to proceed.
The first step would usually be to fit a normal linear regression model and then plot the residuals vs fitted values to view the mean-variance relationship.
That is more relevant than examining the marginal distribution of the y-values.
Since your $y$ values are reaction times, and are presumably strictly positive, they probably have an increasing mean-variance relationship.
I would try log-transforming and then fit the linear regression again, to see if that removes the mean-variance dependence.

**References**

Ritchie ME, Silver J, Oshlack A, Holmes M, Diyagama D, Holloway A, Smyth GK (2007). A comparison of background correction methods for two-colour microarrays. *Bioinformatics* 23, 2700-2707.

Silver JD, Ritchie ME, Smyth GK (2009). Microarray background correction: maximum likelihood estimation for the normal-exponential convolution. *Biostatistics* 10, 352-363.

Xie Y, Wang X, Story M (2009). Statistical methods of background correction for Illumina beadarray data. *Bioinformatics* 25, 751–757.

Shi W, Oshlack A, Smyth GK (2010). Optimizing the noise versus bias trade-off for Illumina Whole Genome Expression BeadChips. *Nucleic Acids Research* 38, e204.